# Why Does Bitcoin Core Use Autotools?

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling

Why does Bitcoin Core use [Autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Autotools) instead of checking a Makefile into source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because checking for compiler features, without Automake/CMake/Ninja/Bazel with only Makefile and C++ preprocessor is hard and unelegant.

And C++ preprocessor can't be used to make full-compile feature tests. If the compiler supports AVX256, a relatively new instruction set, that doesn't mean the assembler supports it too. There are "fail if can't compile completely"s in the autoconf file.